# Correct textual name for <<

Tags: shell, pipe

I've just come across the `<<` command, used like so:

```
cat > outfile.txt <<EOF
Multi-line content
that will be written to outfile.txt
EOF
```

Now, I've no idea what this is called, but I'd quite like to know it's name, primarily so I can go and search and find out more about its syntax. Sadly, Googling for "<<" just doesn't work.

Comment: Conveniently, I was just trying to figure out how to use it with a stdout redirection last night and couldn't get it. I kept trying to do `EOF > outfile.txt` at the end, which doesn't work well

Comment: POSIX 2008 > Shell Command Language > Redirection > [Here-Document](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04)

Comment: `man bash` and look for `<<` (in my `man` viewer, the search command is the `/` character, so `/<<` gets me to the right section).

Comment: For an experiment, you should have tried 'cat <<HERE'. echo doesn't read stdin.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does << work and what is it called?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34808/how-does-work-and-what-is-it-called)

Comment: See also [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/23408)

Comment: Most shells also supports `cat <<< this line is fed to cat` (a one-line here-doc) which can be handy sometimes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's called a "Here document".

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document

Answer (score 8):

It's form of redirection called a **[here document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document)** or **heredoc**. It redirects the contents of the given in-line document to a command.  The document is delimited by the given word (`EOT` below).  Quoting the word or part of the word after `<<` creates a quoted here-document that the shell will not perform expansions in.

```bsh
$ tac << EOT
> 123
> 456
> EOT
456
123
```

Answer (score 1):

In a Unix context it really is known as a "here document."  I believe that the "heredoc" construct comes from PHP, Perl, and other scripting languages, and for shell scripting I'd tend to stick with "here document."