# How does << work and what is it called?

Tags: bash, shell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Correct textual name for <<](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2888/correct-textual-name-for)

I am learning about Go and saw this usage I've never seen before (from http://golang.org/doc/install.html):

```
$ cat >hello.go <<EOF
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("hello, world\n")
}
EOF
```

Curious, I tried it myself:

```
$ echo <<EOF hello
> asdf
> asdf
> EOF
hello

$ echo <<test hello
> hello
> test
hello
```

I am aware of redirecting standard input to read from a file instead (via < operator), but I've never seen <<, and not with this start/end delimiter business.  (I know about >> for appending but this seems different)  It's extremely hard to search for <<; could someone point me in the right direction?