# < and << in UNIX /Linux

Tags: shell, io-redirection, cat, here-document

What are the operators `<<`and `<` used for in Linux?

For example

```
cat << abc.txt
```

Comment: Related question: [Correct textual name for <<](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2888/correct-textual-name-for)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<` is used to redirect input.  Saying

```
command < file
```

executes `command` with `file` as input.

The `<<` syntax is referred to as a [here document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document).  The string following `<<` is a *delimiter* indicating the start and end of the here document.

```
$ cat abc.txt
cat: abc.txt: No such file or directory
$ cat << abc.txt
> Hello!
> Hey :)
> abc.txt
Hello!
Hey :)
$
```

`<<` doesn't indicate any sort of indirection.

---

You might also want to refer to [redirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29) and [here document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document).

Comment: I personnaly  still don't understand

Comment: @Kiwy What is it that you don't understand?

Comment: Well reading it third time I start to understand you should express it as a end of input delimiter instead it would be way more clear than writing some script and explaining after.

Comment: @devnull : so, `<<` will act as input if i say grep `"somestring" << filename.txt` ...just asking to clear out my head on this!!

Comment: @NoobEditor In your example, `filename.txt` would be treated as a __delimiter__.  Nothing would be read from the file.

Comment: @Kiwy I rephrased the answer.  Hope it's more clear now.

Comment: I see that. that's better ;-)

Comment: @devnull : ok..its pretty clear, upvoted...and accepted ( *but if some1 else comes up with better answer then u have competition* )...can u give me some reference urls where i can see both of these commands in work????

Comment: @NoobEditor You might want to refer to a couple of links added in the answer.